# Firebase keeps asking me to go into venv

Tags: firebase, python-venv

I keep getting this issue: Error: Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK: Missing virtual environment at venv directory. Did you forget to run 'python3.11 -m venv venv'?

This happens even after i run it, inside a virtual environment, and have source/venv/bin/activated it.

tried running the venv. Also tried re-initializing within that.